# How to share interactive video in facebook?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a simple html5 interactive video , you can see it here live

[live demo](https://meed.audiencevideo.com/onlyvideo.html)

I want something like this

[Expected result](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7A2Wdj1vepA)

I tried something like this

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://meed.audiencevideo.com/onlyvideo.html title="Share on
                                                                                Facebook" target="_blank" id="facebookbtn" class="share-btn btn
                                                                                btn-facebook">
                                                                                <img src="images/Facebook.png">


</a>
```

the only image has shared no video or whatsoever

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: Sharing interactive HTML5 content directly into newsfeed is only available for a limited set of Facebook partners, AFAIK. Instant Games are also based on HTML5, but I am not sure if you could publish your kind of content as that, Facebook might object that it is not actually a game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Facebook SDK for javascript, Please go through the below steps.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

If sharing doesn't work you can try for Post option.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title> Publish </title>
</head>
<body>
      <div id='fb-root'></div>
      <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>

      <input type="button" value="Publish " onclick="publish(); return false;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({appId: "APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

function publish()
{
      var feed = {
            method: 'feed',
            picture: 'THUMB',
            link: 'http://google.com',
            name: 'Google',
            description: 'DESCRIPTION',
            source: 'PATH_TO_SWF_OR_PLAYER_WITH_PARAMETERS',
            type: 'video',
      };

      function callback(response){
            if(response && response.post_id !== undefined) {
                  alert('published');
            }
      }

      FB.ui(feed, callback);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

More information [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog).

Or else you can use other alternatives

1. https://www.addthis.com/
2. https://www.addtoany.com/

Answer (score 1):

You might get some help by joining the "Developers on Facebook" group. (https://developers.facebook.com/)
It would be tough I guess to replicate the expected result as it is in patent pending status.